# image with overlay text on ion card?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm very new to Ionic and I have a simple question that I couldn't find in the documentation.

Is there any way to use Ionic classes to simply align the "Disc 20%" text on the center of the images?

Something like this image:

[image]

The code I currently have is:

```
<ion-content class="card-background-page">
  <ion-card *ngFor="let periode of items" (click)="dismiss(periode)">
    <ion-list>
      <div class="item item-input-inset">
        <button ion-item class="item item-input-wrapper" value="{{periode.Productid}}">
          <ion-avatar item-start>
            <img src="assets/imgs/home/bgCashback.png" style="border-radius:0%;width:72px;height:72px;">
          </ion-avatar>
          <div class="card-img">Disc 20%</div>
          <div class="card-title" style="color:#838383;font-size:13px;font-weight:400">
            {{ periode.title_promo }}
          </div>
          <div text-wrap class="card-subtitle" style="color:#9c9c9c;margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;font-size: 12px;">
            {{ periode.description }}
          </div>
        </button>
      </div>
    </ion-list>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col></ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-note>Valid Until: {{ periode.end_date | date: 'dd MMM yyyy' }}</ion-note>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-card>
```

and the scss :

```
card-background-page {
    .ion-card {
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .card-img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 36%;
        font-size: 2.0em;
        width: 100%;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #fff;
      }
}
```

Comment: Can you upload now you'r getting result?

Comment: @stalinrajindian https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFQIM.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with below ionic and CSS. Don't use inline CSS.

ionic code:

```
<ion-content class="card-background-page">
  <ion-card *ngFor="let periode of items" (click)="dismiss(periode)">
    <ion-list>
      <div class="item item-input-inset">
        <button ion-item class="item item-input-wrapper" value="{{periode.Productid}}">
          <ion-avatar style="background: url("assets/imgs/home/bgCashback.png"); item-start>
            <div class="card-img">Disc 20%</div>
          </ion-avatar>
          <div class="card-desc-cvr">          
            <div class="card-title">
              {{ periode.title_promo }}
            </div>
            <div text-wrap class="card-subtitle">
              {{ periode.description }}
            </div>
         </div>
        </button>
      </div>
    </ion-list>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col></ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-note>Valid Until: {{ periode.end_date | date: 'dd MMM yyyy' }}</ion-note>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

CSS:

```
.card-background-page {
 .ion-card {
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
    }      

    ion-avatar{
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 72px;
      height: 72px;
      line-height: 72px;
      background-size: 72px 72px;     
    }

    .card-desc-cvr{
       float: left;
      }

      .card-subtitle{
        color:#9c9c9c;
        margin: 0px;
        font-size: 12px;
      }

      .card-title{
        color:#838383;
        font-size:13px;
        font-weight:400
      }
}
```

Comment: if you have live url?

Comment: I have edited the code Please try to this: <ion-avatar style="background: url("assets/imgs/home/bgCashback.png"); item-start>

Comment: <ion-avatar style="background: url('assets/imgs/home/bgCashback.png');" item-start>
                <div class="card-img">Disc 20%</div>
              </ion-avatar>

tested, nice pals. but the image became too large https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgkx4.jpg

Comment: I have updated the CSS. Please add style icon-avatar{text-align: center;background-size: 72px 72px;}

Comment: still hasn't changed